# Values below "Starting IP address" in linksys router.

Tags: router, ip-address, arp

In my basics setup in linksys router, I've set **Starting IP address** to `192.168.1.100`. How can you explain that in **ARP/RARP Table** I can see users with addresses `192.168.1.25` and `192.168.1.26`?

Answer (score 2):

Because your DHCP range has nothing to do with ARP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed that these are settings only for DHCP. Thank you.